# Why the fading in/out of the saving text is fading only one time when saving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The post is a bit long but the scripts are connected to each other.

When the game start first time it's saving after 3 seconds and fading for 3 seconds.
but in the game later when it's saving again it's showing the save text fading only once.

In this script I'm making the save and also set the time to start the saving and the time it will fade in/out :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FadeInOutSaveGameText fadeInOutSaveGame;
    public float timeToStartSaving;
    public float savingFadeInOutTime;

    private List<GameObject> objectsToSave = new List<GameObject>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        SaveSystem.Init();

        var objectsWithGenerateGuid = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GenerateGuid>().ToList();
        if (objectsWithGenerateGuid.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsWithGenerateGuid.Count; i++)
            {
                objectsToSave.Add(objectsWithGenerateGuid[i].gameObject);
            }
        }

        Debug.Log("Start");

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSave.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log($"{i}");
            Debug.Log($"{objectsToSave[i].name}");
        }

        Debug.Log("End Init");
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        SaveGame saveGame = new SaveGame();
        saveGame.saveObjects = new List<SaveObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSave.Count; i++)
        {
            SaveObject saveObject = new SaveObject();
            saveObject.transformSaver = new TransformSaver();
            Debug.Log($"{i}");
            Debug.Log($"{objectsToSave[i].name}");
            saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID = objectsToSave[i].GetComponent<GenerateGuid>().uniqueGuidID;
            var x = objectsToSave[i].GetComponents<Component>();
            var stateQueryComponent = x.Where(component => component is IStateQuery).ToList();
            List<KeyToValue> componentsState = new List<KeyToValue>();
            foreach (var z in stateQueryComponent)
            {
                var w = z as IStateQuery;
                componentsState.Add(new KeyToValue(w.UniqueId.ToString(), w.GetState()));
            }

            saveObject.transformSaver.position = objectsToSave[i].transform.position;
            saveObject.transformSaver.rotation = objectsToSave[i].transform.rotation;
            saveObject.transformSaver.scaling = objectsToSave[i].transform.localScale;

            saveObject.componentsState = componentsState;
            saveGame.saveObjects.Add(saveObject);
        }

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveGame);
        SaveSystem.Save(json);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        Dictionary<string, GameObject> uniqueIdToObject = objectsToSave
            .ToDictionary(o => o.GetComponent<GenerateGuid>().uniqueGuidID, o => o);
        var saveString = SaveSystem.Load();
        if (saveString != null)
        {
            SaveGame saveGame = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveGame>(saveString);
            foreach (var saveObject in saveGame.saveObjects)
            {
                List<KeyToValue> loadedComponents = saveObject.componentsState;
                var objectToSetState = uniqueIdToObject[saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID];

                objectToSetState.transform.position = saveObject.transformSaver.position;
                objectToSetState.transform.rotation = saveObject.transformSaver.rotation;
                objectToSetState.transform.localScale = saveObject.transformSaver.scaling;

                var y = objectToSetState.GetComponents<Component>();
                var z = y.Where(component => component is IStateQuery).ToList();
                Dictionary<string, IStateQuery> zz = z.ToDictionary(sq => (sq as IStateQuery).UniqueId.ToString(), sq => sq as IStateQuery);

                foreach (KeyToValue keyvalue in loadedComponents)
                {
                    zz[keyvalue.Key].SetState(keyvalue.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator SaveWithTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToStartSaving);

        Save();

        StartCoroutine(fadeInOutSaveGame.OverAllTime(savingFadeInOutTime));
    }
}
```

At the bottom I created the to save with time :

```
public IEnumerator SaveWithTime()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToStartSaving);
    
            Save();
    
            StartCoroutine(fadeInOutSaveGame.OverAllTime(savingFadeInOutTime));
        }
```

The method OverAllTime make the fading depending on the time I set in this case 3 seconds :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FadeInOutSaveGameText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Canvas canvas;
    public float fadingSpeed;

    private bool stopFading = false;
    private const float THRESHOLD = 0.01F;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
     
    }

    IEnumerator CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime(Canvas canvas, float duration)
    {
        float alphaColor = canvas.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha;

        while (true)
        {
            alphaColor = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * duration) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
            canvas.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = alphaColor;

            // only break, if current alpha value is close to 0 or 1
            if (stopFading && Mathf.Abs(alphaColor) <= THRESHOLD)//if (stopFading && (Mathf.Abs(alphaColor) <= THRESHOLD || Mathf.Abs(alphaColor - 1) <= THRESHOLD))
            {
                break;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator OverAllTime(float time)
    {
        StartCoroutine(CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime(canvas, fadingSpeed));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        stopFading = true;
    }
}
```

And in this script at the bottom I'm starting the save :

```
private void Update()
    {
        if(dimLights.lightsDimmed == true && lightsDim == false && unlockCarte.HasOpened() == true
             && MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame == false)
        {
            m_state.naviLightsIntensity = dimLights.lightsToDim[0].intensity;
            lightsDim = true;
            var brainBlendTime = Camera.main.GetComponent<CinemachineBrain>();
            saveLoad.timeToStartSaving = brainBlendTime.m_DefaultBlend.m_Time;
            StartCoroutine(saveLoad.SaveWithTime());
        }
    }
```

I'm setting the timeToStartSaving to the time it takes to blend from one cinemachine camera to another camera in this case 5 seconds.

I used break points and it's getting to the SaveWithTime method when the value of timeToStartSaving is 5 and the value of savingFadeInOutTime stay 3 as before. Only the timeToStartSaving variable vlaue was 3 and changed to 5.

but ion the game the fading happens only once one time instead 3 times.
in the start of the game first time saving it does fading 3 times for 3 seconds. but on the second saving for some reason it's fading only one time even if the value of savingFadeInOutTime is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset `stopFading`, otherwise your loop will always break after the first time reaching the zero threshold.

```
public IEnumerator OverAllTime(float time)
{
    stopFading = false; // reset this, otherwise it stays true, after the first run
    StartCoroutine(CanvasAlphaChangeOverTime(canvas, fadingSpeed));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

    stopFading = true;
}
```